# C++: Duplicating a Binary Tree with Doubled up Nodes

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-tree

The goal is to create a copy of a tree, where each node has a value that is double the value of the original node. The function should be implemented recursively. I have written some code which creates a new tree but the error is that my code never creates a "full copy", its always only the first two levels.

```
Node* doubleUp(Node* root) {
int value = root->data;
Node* newroot = new Node(value*2);

if(root->left != NULL)
{
    int value = (root->left)->data;
    Node* left = new Node(value*2);
    newroot->left = left;
    doubleUp(newroot->left);
}
if(root->right != NULL)
{
    int value = (root->right)->data;
    Node* right = new Node(value*2);
    newroot->right = right;
    doubleUp(newroot->right);
}
return newroot;
}
```

I understand why its doing this, the function always creates a "newroot", when instead after the first level it should be just taking the parameter passed to it. But not sure what to do to fix it.

Here is a sample tree, using the Node struct.

```
Node a(0), b(4), c(2), d(1), e(5), f(6), g(3), h(7);
a.left=&b;
a.right=&c;
c.left=&f;
b.left=&d;
b.right=&e;
d.left=&g;
d.right=&h;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the return value of doubleUp of the left and right subtree, and so your recursion is wrong.(Your calls are actually leaking memory out!) What you actually wanted to do, was something like:

```
Node* doubleUp(Node* root) {
    Node* doubledRoot = new Node(root->data * 2);
    if (root->left) {
         newRoot->left = doubleUp(root->left);
    }
    if (root->left) {
         newRoot->right = doubleUp(root->right);
    }
    return doubledRoot;
}
```

Bear in mind, I haven't actually tested this code, so it might be broken slightly, but should convey the basic idea nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little simpler

```
Node* doubleUp(Node* root) 
{
  if (root == nullptr)
    return nullptr

  Node* newroot = new Node(root->data*2);
  newroot->left = doubleUp(root->left);
  newroot->right = doubleUp(root->right);

  return newroot;
}
```